# How to force derived class to implement a static function which receive as parameter an object of the derived class

Tags: c++

I defined a class A, which define a static function. Let's say

```
class A{

  // virtual functions

  // the function create the object and sets its fields according to inputs
  static bool create(vector<string> inputs, A* a);

}
```

Is it possible to force the derived classes to implement the `compute` function in the following way?

```
class B : public class A{

  // virtual functions

  static bool create(vector<string> inputs, B* b);
}

class C : public class A{

  // virtual functions

  static bool create(vector<string> inputs, C* c);
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like this should be a non-static function and take only the string as a parameter.

Comment: Don't define it in `A`, call it on `B`. You'll then get an error if `print` is not defined in `B`. In this respect it resembles a pure virtual function, only it's not virtual.

Comment: @Borgleader Sorry, I simplified to much the example. Now should be more clear. The fact is that I want to modify the object that I pass as parameter based on `inputs`. I don't want to do it with a constructor because the operation can fail.

Comment: why it cannot be a virtual vunction?

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 because it has to instantiate the object.

Comment: @user3516222 If it has to instantiate the object, it should be a constructor. If it's simply modifying an object, it should just be a non-static member function. If neither of those work, it sounds like you want the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: @EricFinn I would avoid the constructor because if the inputs are not well formatted the function should return false. I would avoid the factory method because I would like to avoid the need of changing the factory implementation when a new sub-class is defined.

Comment: @user3516222 If the inputs are not well formatted you can throw an exception from the constructor. If the class can exist in a valid state without running this function, then it can simply be a pure virtual member function.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way. "Forcing" a class to implement a function can only be achieved with pure virtual functions (and even then you don't really force it, because the derived class may itself stay abstract).

Think about it. You are trying to combine two incompatible mechanisms of C++.

`virtual` always has something to do with **objects**. You have an object of some derived type and a pointer or reference to the base type. The whole idea of a virtual function only makes sense with objects.

`static`, on the contrary, does *not* require an object. The reason you use `static` in the first place is precisely that: you want to call something without having an object.

So it's just two different worlds, really. You are asking *"How can I make the compiler choose a function at run-time depending on the derived type of an object without having an object?"*

Perhaps what you are really looking for are **templates**. With a template, you can require that a type, when used in a certain context, has a certain function:

```
template <class T>
void f()
{
    T::compute(my_vector);
}
```

In any case, it seems that your actual goal is to solve a higher-level problem, but you are using the wrong tool for that.

Comment: May I ask, what if word `static` is removed from OP's question? Can I force the derived class to implement a function that take its type as parameter? Using templates seem to lose some benefit of base class. E.g., shared implementation of base class functions (code bloat) and different implementations of interface functions (er... use template specialization)?